# How can I use my xampp server so that everyone from the outer web can acces it

Tags: webserver, xampp, port80

I'm now having problems with this for over a week.
I'm running a minecraft server on my computer. Therefore I used no-ip.org to have a "fixed" ip. I forwared all ports for the server and my friends can access without any problems.
Later I thought I could make a little Homegape for statistics and stuff. So I installed xampp. I forwarded the ports 80, 8080, 8000, 7171. I (and everybody else in my local network) can access it via the no-ip.org address. But nobody else! (And I want to repeat that people can reach my computer over the minecraft port (25565) and no other port!)

How can I fix that problem? I'm pretty sure there is a simple node in one of the config's which I haven't seen yet. I googled for days. So I found out that I should forward these ports. But that's all I could find.

My firewall is (for testing of course!) disabled!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I am using cox and they are blocking port 80. Well now I am using https and port 443 and everything works fine!

Answer (score 6):

Probably your firewall is blocking xampp or apache. If you are at windows 7, try to go to Control Panel -> System Security -> windows firewal > allow a program through windows firewall and then search "apache" or "xampp" and mark to allow public and private connections

Additionally you can try this also:

- Launch "Windows Firewall"
- Go to "Advanced Settings"
- Select "Inbound Rules" in the left pane
- Select "New Rule" in the right pane
- In the New Inbound Rule Wizard, select "Port" as Rule Type, then click on "Next"
- Select "TCP and put "80" (and any other ports you want to open) in "Specific local ports", then click on "Next"
- Select "Allow the connection", then click on "Next"
- Select the network location where the rule should apply (select them all if you're not sure), then click on "Next"
- Give a name and an optional description

Comment: Sorry, I totally forgot to mention that!

My firewall is for reasons for testing COMPLETELY off! And I even allowed ALL ports mentioned above!

Comment: I already port forwarded it. And as far as I know does port forwarding exist to work around this firewall. The ports are free for my computer. And the port for my Minecraft server does work! (tested it several times!)