# How can I preview a localhost wordpress website online?

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp, web-hosting

This is a question I've had for a long time & I really hope that there is an answer but I'm also prepared for the answer to be no..

I'm developing a Wordpress website for my friend's new business on my computer & hosting it locally using MAMP. I really need to preview it for her but I live in London & she lives in NYC.
I know that with simple HTML/JavaScript web site/pages I can use websites like bitballon.com but I'm have no idea if there is an equivalent for Wordpress websites.

I really don't want to purchase hosting until it is completely finished, therefore I'm wondering: is a way in which I can preview a localhost MAMP website online for someone to view on another device without purchasing hosting?

All suggestions, comments, answers, are welcome and much appreciated!

Comment: Can be tricky but it's possible (I did it ages ago): [DIY Hosting Using No-IP & MAMP](http://www.noip.com/support/knowledgebase/diy-hosting-using-no-ip-mamp/) & [MAMP PRO Documentation > Servers and Services > Dynamic DNS](http://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Servers-and-Services/Dynamic-DNS/)

Answer (score 2):

All you need is any free hosting with PHP and MySQL. If you want to quickly move your WordPress website from localhost to server, you can use a plugin like [Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/).

However, it can be a pain to move it again and again, every time something changes, so you can edit some of the code "live" on the server.

Comment: This sounds great! Do you have a suggestion for any free hosting with PHP & MySQL?

Comment: I have no idea, because the last time I used a free one was like 5 years ago. Type a "free hosting", choose any from the top 10 results and it should be fine for a website preview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check this following option they have option for free hosting

```
https://in.000webhost.com/
https://www.5gbfree.com/
https://www.freehosting.com
```

And if anyone who have reseller account can provide you little space for demo

Answer (score 0):

Even though i only used xampp and not mamp, i think you can configure it so that you are hosting it on your pc. You will need to configure the httpd.conf so somebody from outside is able to access it but there are plenty of guides around for that.

[How can I use my xampp server so that everyone from the outer web can acces it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14432760/how-can-i-use-my-xampp-server-so-that-everyone-from-the-outer-web-can-acces-it)